# Creating Heatmaps with Heatmap.2

Tags: r

Hi Guys: forgive my ignorance as I am completely novice in R but am trying to create a heatmap using heatmap.2. I can create the map but the margin and row labels look like one big black smear across the page and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Also the default behavior is to put the row labels on the right and I would like them on the left.

The code I am playing around with is:

```
    mycolors<-c("green","grey","red")

    #no clustering or reordering


    heatmap.2(WIDEMAT,col=mycolors,
      dendrogram="none",
      key=F,
      Colv="NA",
      Rowv="NA",
      main="NQF DATA",
      xlab="Subject ID",
      ylab="")
```

ANy tips would be much appreciated

Comment: Describe the data being used and show evidence that you have read through the help page.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can take a look at `d3heatmap` package. Also as mentioned by @42 can you `dput(WIDEMAT)`and print the output here please

```
rm(list = ls())
library(d3heatmap)
d3heatmap(mtcars, scale = "column")
```

[image]